# NPM install doesn't install all packages

Tags: node.js, git

I use **Buddy.works** to upload my project files from **Git** repository when I merge my develop branch in master (pipeline).

I have one pipeline who's make the works, this pipeline sends the files to my server, then runs the command `npm install --only production --verbose`

I get the impression that NPM does not install all packages.

No package-lock.json file is sent during the transfer but it appears after the transfer.

> npm install --only production --verbose added 33 packages, removed 165 packages, updated 10 packages and moved 1 package in 7.94s

Why removed 165 packages? Why updated 10 packages? And why added only 33 packages?

Comment: Is this building from clean every time?

Comment: Yes, the building is clean every time...